# Stopping an $interval function with a promise attached

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setinterval

Inside of an angular controller I'm trying to stop an interval.  Is it not possible to stop the interval if there is a .then promise chained to it?

Why does the stopCount function work here

```
var stop = $interval(function(){
    console.log('testing interval');
  }, 1000);

$scope.stopCount = function(){
  $interval.cancel(stop);
}
```

but not here with the .then

```
var stop = $interval(function(){
    console.log('testing interval');
  }, 1000)
  .then(function(){
     console.log('complete')
  });

$scope.stopCount = function(){
  $interval.cancel(stop);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100585/confusion-about-how-the-promise-returned-by-interval-works-compared-to-timeout

Comment: $timeout will return a promise that you can call .then on, because in a sense it is like a promise. It does something after a certain amount of time. Although interval is different, it just keeps going. So the ONLY thing you can do once you start it, is stop it

Comment: If you would like to execute the console.log after 1 second, then just plug in $timeout instead of $interval and all should work :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  So there is not a way to run a function after the interval has been canceled?

Comment: Think about this. the .then method returns a NEW promise. So you are trying to stop the NEW proimse, not the original One.

Comment: Don't call then directly after the $interval. Instead, call it on the stop variable after the interval has been set

Comment: Then your promise should work and you should get the default behaviour. The .then should be called on EACH completed cycle of the interval, as it is notified when the interval restarts. And since 'stop' is referencing the promsise that $interval returned, you should be able to stop it :)

Comment: EDIT: Skipped all the comments and just submitted an answer. Let me know how it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

```
// The problem is that stop is not storing the promise of $interval
// It's storing the promise returned by the .then method
var stop = $interval(function(){
  console.log('testing interval');
}, 1000)
.then(function(){
  console.log('complete')
});

$scope.stopCount = function(){
  $interval.cancel(stop);
}


// Try this
// Now stop is using $intervals promise,
// not .then. We'll call .then separately below
var stop = $interval(function(){
  console.log('testing interval');
}, 1000);

// Now we can cancel the 'stop' interval below
// This promise has to have a success callback
// AND an error callback.
stop.then(function(){
  console.log('complete')
}, function(err) {
  console.log('Uh oh, error!', err);
});

$scope.stopCount = function(){
  $interval.cancel(stop);
}
```

Comment: It does stop the interval but I don't see the 'complete' get logged when I stop.

Comment: Hm, this is the difference between $timeout and $interval. $interval should call your console.log one EVERY iteration of the interval. $timeout would only call your console.log after it has finished

Comment: It sounds like you aren't even getting that. The result of this code should be that 'complete' is logged every second.

Comment: I do get testing interval every second

Comment: But not  complete? they should both be logged, first testing, then complete. on EACH iteration

Comment: This doesn't use the .then method at all. Going to snoop around as to why it doesn't work, doesn't work for me either.

Comment: If I use a success and error callback with the stop promise I am able to get it to log the 'complete'

Comment: Wonderful! I updated my answer to include that for future-comers :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you obviously dont completely understand about promises... The reason this dosent work:

```
var stop = $interval(function(){
    console.log('testing interval');
  }, 1000)
  .then(function(){
     console.log('complete')
  });

$scope.stopCount = function(){
  $interval.cancel(stop);
}
```

Is because you have two promises... The first one is the milliseconds which is 1000/ 1second. And the other one is a .then() promise. You cant use two promises in one function.

If you see the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)  You see that the syntax for $interval is:

$interval(fn, delay, [count], [invokeApply], [Pass]);

And for the cancel function this is the syntax

```
$interval.cancel([promise]);
```

Comment: How is $interval a promise of milliseconds? You can only cancel it. On a different note you can ABSOLUTELY use multiple callbacks on the same promise. Unless I misunderstood what you meant?

Comment: Im not talking about multiple callbacks on the same promise. I said Multiple promises.  @DustinStiles

Comment: That part is totally true. I still don't understand the bit about there being two promises. $interval returns a promise, which is the only promise in the code. $interval returns a promise (.then) and that is it? Is there something I'm not seeing?

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, writing my own answer cleared it up :)

Comment: Although the bit about using two promises IN one function is very confusing. It's true, but not what's happening with the OP's code. I think what you meant to say was, you can't store two promises in the same variable :)